# Unable to find particular file

Tags: c#, windows, console, exe

When in my program I try to launch particular exe-file "nvidia-smi.exe" (NVIDIA System Management Interface program), I receive the error "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception. The system cannot find the file specified"

```
string directoryPath = "C:\\";
string fileName = "nvidia-smi.exe";
Console.WriteLine(System.IO.File.Exists(directoryPath + fileName)); //true
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = directoryPath;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
proc.Start(); //Error. The system cannot find the file specified
```

But at the same time I can :

1) Launch the other files from the same directory (exe, bat etc)

2) Successfully to execute the file I needed "nvidia-smi.exe" if relocate it to my project's directory and do not use the property "proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory".

-----------------The answer is (Thanks for help!)------------------

you need this :

```
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\";
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "nvidia-smi.exe";
```

Or this :

```
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\nvidia-smi.exe";
```

Comment: Not sure but perhaps the exe needs to write something in the current folder and the root of the system disk is protected from write attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute` to true, the behavior of `WorkingDirectory` will be as you expect it to be. Otherwise, you will have to either specify the absolute path for the `FileName`, or make sure your executable is in your environment path.

Relevant documentation:

[UseShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute(v=vs.110).aspx)

[WorkingDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx)